# How to list only active records with select from?

Tags: php, codeigniter, where-clause, query-builder

I need to make a query to return only active records which in this case are `imo_status` == 1

What is the best way to make this query? I'm using CI3

Below is the source code.

```
// LISTA OS AGENCIAMENTOS NO BANCO DE DADOS
public function getProperties()
{   

    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('ci_properties');
    $this->db->where('imo_status' == 1);
        return $this->db->get("ci_properties")->result_array();

    /*$query = $this->db->get("ci_properties");
    return $query->result_array();*/
}
```

Comment: For a concise, one-liner model method, [use `get_where()` like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60740055/2943403): `return $this->db->get_where('ci_properties', ['imo_status' => 1])->result_array();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You build the query then don't use it:

```
return $this->db->get("ci_properties")->result_array();
```

This wipes out the query builder and basically does a 'get all' from 'ci_properties'. To use you're query:

```
$query = $this->db->get();        
return $query->result();
```

This is because you have already specified the table in the 'from' part, get('table name'), will get all.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this

```
public function getProperties()
{   

    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('ci_properties');
    $this->db->where('imo_status', 1);
        $query = $this->db->get();        
        return $query->result_array();
}
```